# Which raw processors interpret distortion/CA correction from Micro Four Thirds cameras?

Tags: software, linux, micro-four-thirds, distortion, chromatic-aberration

I've been thinking about Micro Four Thirds, which in many cases encodes distortion and chromatic aberration correction into the raw files. But, the raw processor I currently use (Bibble) ignores this data, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what software does use it - for example, does Lightroom use its own database (as Bibble does) or the data in the raw files? Bonus points for info on Linux software, but I'm to the point where I'm willing to switch to Mac or Windows too.

I would also be reasonably happy if there were separate software that could create profiles that I could import into Bibble ([specs for that](http://support.bibblelabs.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=94&t=15277), and it seems like the parameters are fairly standard). Since it would be easy to create corrected and uncorrected JPEGs (using Bibble and in-camera, respectively), that seems like it could be straightforward.

Comment: AFAIK, all Windows software work under Linux with the right VM. I use Parallels under OpenSUSE to run Lightroom. About the data, perhaps you should write to Olympus. They probably know who they gave it to.

Comment: I'm a Lightroom guy, but I really like the idea of working on linux.  I am keeping a weather eye on Bibble.  I may jump over and join you one of these days!

Answer (score 2):

In the thread from Bibble Labs that you linked to, there is a post that refers to a tutorial on using [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/calibration/en.shtml) to create lens correction profiles. I used that technique over a year ago with Bibble and found that it worked. Hugin runs under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Some folks on DPReview [say that Lightroom/Camera Raw apply the embedded corrections automatically](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1041&message=34944594), e.g.:

> Adobe applies all the lens corrections that either Panasonic or Olympus lenses and bodies inject into the raw files from the lens' firmware with both the Camera Raw plugin and Lightroom. There is no issue if these are your raw processing tools.

See also [this Adobe thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3003806?tstart=-1), which indicates that the correction is applied automatically and cannot be turned off:

> The distortion correction is applied automatically based on the available metadata (from the camera + lens system). The resulting shape of the image should closely match the result of shooting JPEGs. It cannot be disabled in CR/LR.